# SQL, PHP (Laravel). How can I get tree with conditions

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel

I have table:
`task_categories`: id, name, parent_id, _lft, _rgt.
`team_members`: id, name.
`task_category_team_member`: id, task_category_id, team_member_id

How can I get all descendants for `task_categories` where relation task_category_team_member exists.

For example:
Task 1
Task 1.2 (parent is Task 1)
Task 1.2.1 (parent is Task 1.2)
Task 2.

In `task_category_team_member` I have relation for Task 1.2.1.
If I do

```
$task = Task::where('id', 1)->first(); // it's Task 1
$descendantsQuery = $task->descendants();

$descendantsQuery->select(['task_categories.*']);
// $descendantsQuery->where('is_public', true);
$descendantsQuery->orWhereHas('taskCategoryTeamMember', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('team_member_id', $this->taskCategoryPolicy->teamMember->id);
});
```

It returns Task 1.2.1 because it has relation, but Task 1.2.1 is parent for Task 1.2, if I haven't access for parent I can't get access for child even team member has access to this child

How can I do?
Can someone provide some SQL example how to do it